# How do you catch GeneratorExit in a generator that has yet been iterated?

Tags: python

E.g.,

```
In [33]: def gener():
    ...:   try:
    ...:     print('hi')
    ...:     yield 1
    ...:     print('hi 2')
    ...:     yield 2
    ...:   except:
    ...:     print('Closed: {!r}'.format(sys.exc_info()[1]))
    ...:

In [34]: gener().close()

# ↑ No output!
In [35]: g = gener()

In [36]: next(g)
hi
Out[36]: 1

In [37]: g.close()
Closed: GeneratorExit()
```

Is it not possible to notice the generator's `close()` call if you haven't stepped into the generator, in Python?

(In my actual use-case, one of the arguments to the generator is a resource that the function returning the generator is passing to the generator, *including ownership*. I.e.,

```python
def do_it():
    resource = acquire()
    try:
        return a_generator(resource)()  # pass ownership of the resource
    except:
        resource.close()
```

If you close the generator prior to the first iteration, and the generator can't capture that fact, then the resource is leaked.)

Comment: You could write a class based generator and override the close method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. If the generator hasn't been `next`ed, any `try` clauses inside the body haven't been entered. `close` will throw the `GeneratorExit` at the start of the function, before any exception handling can be set up.

You'll have to change the premises - for example, by introducing a dummy `yield` and `next`ing the generator once in advance:

```
def gen_wrapper():
    gen_iter = _gen()
    next(gen_iter)
    return gen_iter

def _gen():
    try:
        yield
        ...
    finally:
        perform_cleanup()

# Generator returned from gen_wrapper will perform cleanup even if closed immediately.
```

Comment: This was my sneaking suspicion. That's a shame, Python.